# Android: Get N number of push notifications

Tags: java, android, push-notification

What should I do to show N number of push notifications? I have done the following and called it in loop. But the previous notifications get lost when new arrives.

**Code**

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_logo;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                com.example.themomotrail.ShopDetails.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.putExtra("selected", shopName);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same [Notification id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) `0`

Use different id `notificationManager.notify(i, notification);` // i =0, 1, 2 ...

or generate random int.

```
notificationManager.notify((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 100000), notification);
```

Comment: About random ints: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29

Comment: I'm Ok with random :-) Thanks